# how to use trylock out of the run() method in thread class

Tags: java

I'm trying to make room reservation system, I have multi clients access same reservation method.
so I put this method into thread class and I want to make one ReentrantLock to allow one client to access the reservation method.. also this method will be called from another class.
the problem I got is nullPointerException.
this is my code:

```
public class server {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

   ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(9800);
   ReentrantLock roomLock = new ReentrantLock();

   while(true){

       System.out.println("Server ready to recive clint... ");
       Socket k = s.accept();
       System.out.println("Clint "+ s.getInetAddress() +" accept " );

       new myThread(k,roomLock).start();

   }
}
```

}

class myThread extends Thread{

```
Socket s;
public static ReentrantLock roomLock;

public myThread(Socket so, ReentrantLock rl) {

    this.s = so;
    this.roomLock = rl;

}

@Override
public void run(){


}


public static Boolean resRoom(String usname,JRootPane rootPane,Date date1,Date date2,Boolean chbox,int sp){
    Boolean stv = true;

    if(roomLock.tryLock()){

    // my critical section 

     roomLock.unlock();
    }
        return stv;

}
```

}

the method should be static to access it from another class

Comment: Where is the call to resRoom function? You run method doesn't have anything in it too, not sure what the thread is doing either

Comment: @AkshaySrivastava  it will be in JFrame class after I click button

Comment: And where is the NullPointerException?

Comment: @ThomasKläger the NullPointerException occur in roomLock.tryLock

Comment: Are you calling `resRoom()` before the first thread is started? Anyway it is a bad design decision to pass the `ReentrantLock` to the `myThread` constructor and store it in a static instance variable. Better to instantiate it directly in the myThread class: `public static final ReentrantLock roomLock = new ReentrantLock();`

Comment: @ThomasKläger like what you say: NullPointerException not occur but now both clients can access the critical section at same time

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. `server` and `myThread` run on the server side. Why do you write about two clients? Do you have three java programs running?

Comment: @ThomasKläger I'm sorry to make you confused, the myThread class actually for the clients to have multi client, and the resRoom method will be call up from the client side, hope you get my case clearly.

Comment: But if you have different clients, where is then the critical section? Since each client has it's own copy of the data no two threads can overwrite each others information.

Comment: @ThomasKläger actually they share same database